# How to trim the video using AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, video

Iam able to record the video by using AVFoundation or UIImagePickerController. But i am unable to trim the video from one particular second to another particular duration/time. Can any one help me.

Thanks,
Siva Krishna.

Comment: Found this question while looking for something to trim an existing video. Trimming captured videos is relatively straight forward. But getting that Trim window to show up seems to elude me. I hope my answer below helps.

Answer (score 19):

You can have the UIImagePickerController enable trimming

```
UIImagePickerController *videoRecorder = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];         
        NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoRecorder.sourceType];
        NSLog(@"Available types for source as camera = %@", sourceTypes);
        if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie] ) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                            message:@"Device Not Supported for video Recording."                                                                       delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"No",nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            return;
        }
        videoRecorder.allowsEditing = YES;
```

Unfortunately after you get back from the imagePickerController, You are forced to convert the video manually.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    if ([self.popoverLibraryBrowser isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [self.popoverLibraryBrowser dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || 
        [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) { // movie != video
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];


        NSNumber *start = [info objectForKey:@"_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart"];
        NSNumber *end = [info objectForKey:@"_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd"];

        // if start and end are nil then clipping was not used.
        // You should use the entire video.


        int startMilliseconds = ([start doubleValue] * 1000);
        int endMilliseconds = ([end doubleValue] * 1000);

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSString *outputURL = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output"] ;
        [manager createDirectoryAtPath:outputURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

        outputURL = [outputURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mp4"];
        // Remove Existing File
        [manager removeItemAtPath:outputURL error:nil];


        //[self loadAssetFromFile:videoURL];

        [self.recorder dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil]; 


        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:videoAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL];
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
        CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(startMilliseconds, 1000), CMTimeMake(endMilliseconds - startMilliseconds, 1000));
        exportSession.timeRange = timeRange;

        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            switch (exportSession.status) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                    // Custom method to import the Exported Video
                    [self loadAssetFromFile:exportSession.outputURL];
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                    //
                    NSLog(@"Failed:%@",exportSession.error);
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                    //
                    NSLog(@"Canceled:%@",exportSession.error);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }];



        //NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        //NSString *videoStoragePath;//Set your video storage path to this variable
        //[videoData writeToFile:videoStoragePath atomically:YES];
        //You can store the path of the saved video file in sqlite/coredata here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the source. When I use "*sourceTypes" as "UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera", I am getting "*start and *end time". But when I use "*sourceTypes" as "UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum", I am not getting "start and end" time. What is the problem? How can I get the "start and end" time?

Comment: Did you give them the ability to "Clip" the video ? The portion that populates the editing start and end is the clipping. If you dont clip the video, then these values are left nil which in turn means that the clipping should be skipped and the entire video should be used.

Comment: Please refer the log here http://pastebin.com/uMU1k61T . I am allowing the user to select the frames from the thumbnail. No problem, if i edit the "Camera recorded video" and the problem happens when i try to select the frames from the videos loaded from the album.

Comment: @karthi When using `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum `, the url you get from `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];` is referenced to a trimmed video file, so no need the start and end time. I know that because I get the duration of url from `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];` and compare it with original video duration. [How to get the duration of video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183938/how-to-get-the-time-duration-of-recorded-video-in-iphone-app)

Comment: Instead of checking for a movie *or* a video, you should check if the type conforms to a movie: `UTTypeConformsTo((__bridge CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie) != 0`. That'll be true of movies and videos.

Comment: @TheLazyCoder - Are the string literals `_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart` and `...End` documented somewhere?  In os9, the info dictionary seems to contain only the path of the edited video.

Comment: It's July, 2019 -something changed!  The "_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart" and counterpart "End" objects are now returning nil for me and the UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is now pointing to an actual edited video that is the result of your clipping.  I'm not sure when this started happening - except that my code that checks for valid start and ends was triggered and hey, it just seems to do now what you would have expected it to do.  If someone else can verify this, I think we need to change the accepted answer.  I'm running iOS 12.3.1 on my iPhone Xs.

Answer (score 4):

Swift version of above

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MobileCoreServices

func pickVideo(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {
        let videoRecorder = UIImagePickerController()
        videoRecorder.sourceType = .Camera
        videoRecorder.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        videoRecorder.allowsEditing = true
        videoRecorder.delegate = self

        presentViewController(videoRecorder, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    guard let documentDirectory = try? manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true) else {return}
    guard let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String else {return}
    guard let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL else {return}

    if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie as String || mediaType == kUTTypeVideo as String {
        let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
        let length = Float(asset.duration.value) / Float(asset.duration.timescale)
        print("video length: \(length) seconds")

        let start = info["_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingStart"] as? Float
        let end = info["_UIImagePickerControllerVideoEditingEnd"] as? Float


        var outputURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("output")


        do {
            try manager.createDirectoryAtURL(outputURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            outputURL = outputURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("output.mp4")
        }catch let error {
            print(error)
        }

        //Remove existing file
         _ = try? manager.removeItemAtURL(outputURL)


        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {return}
        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4

        let startTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(start ?? 0), preferredTimescale: 1000)
        let endTime = CMTime(seconds: Double(end ?? length), preferredTimescale: 1000)
        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: startTime, end: endTime)

        exportSession.timeRange = timeRange
        exportSession.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler{
            switch exportSession.status {
            case .Completed:
                print("exported at \(outputURL)")

            case .Failed:
                print("failed \(exportSession.error)")

            case .Cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(exportSession.error)")

            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution fails for some videos. Any suggestions?

Comment: As a programmer, you should know that "Fails" is not an appropriate way of describing a bug/issue

Comment: It was failing for cloud videos, that I debugged and figured out. And I told fails, as I was not able to get a scenario, so thought of asking you, if you encountered any weird problem like this. 
Anyways, I have solved the issue. And next time please talk nicely to any developer.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for swift 4, i have found [there](https://gist.github.com/jakebromberg/098c328d87bd25ec0ae693b877cb933c#file-avassettrim-swift). I did fixes it for my needs, but it's really clear and convenience.

The code:

```
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

extension FileManager {
    func removeFileIfNecessary(at url: URL) throws {
        guard fileExists(atPath: url.path) else {
            return
        }

        do {
            try removeItem(at: url)
        }
        catch let error {
            throw TrimError("Couldn't remove existing destination file: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct TrimError: Error {
    let description: String
    let underlyingError: Error?

    init(_ description: String, underlyingError: Error? = nil) {
        self.description = "TrimVideo: " + description
        self.underlyingError = underlyingError
    }
}

extension AVMutableComposition {
    convenience init(asset: AVAsset) {
        self.init()

        for track in asset.tracks {
            addMutableTrack(withMediaType: track.mediaType, preferredTrackID: track.trackID)
        }
    }

    func trim(timeOffStart: Double) {
        let duration = CMTime(seconds: timeOffStart, preferredTimescale: 1)
        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: duration)

        for track in tracks {
            track.removeTimeRange(timeRange)
        }

        removeTimeRange(timeRange)
    }
}

extension AVAsset {
    func assetByTrimming(timeOffStart: Double) throws -> AVAsset {
        let duration = CMTime(seconds: timeOffStart, preferredTimescale: 1)
        let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: duration)

        let composition = AVMutableComposition()

        do {
            for track in tracks {
                let compositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: track.mediaType, preferredTrackID: track.trackID)
                try compositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: track, at: kCMTimeZero)
            }
        } catch let error {
            throw TrimError("error during composition", underlyingError: error)
        }

        return composition
    }

    func export(to destination: URL) throws {
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) else {
            throw TrimError("Could not create an export session")
        }

        exportSession.outputURL = destination
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4v
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        let group = DispatchGroup()

        group.enter()

        try FileManager.default.removeFileIfNecessary(at: destination)

        exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
            group.leave()
        }

        group.wait()

        if let error = exportSession.error {
            throw TrimError("error during export", underlyingError: error)
        }
    }
}

func time(_ operation: () throws -> ()) rethrows {
    let start = Date()

    try operation()

    let end = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)
    print(end)

let sourceURL =  URL(fileURLWithPath: CommandLine.arguments[1])
let destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: CommandLine.arguments[2])

do {
    try time {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: sourceURL)
        let trimmedAsset = try asset.assetByTrimming(timeOffStart: 1.0)
        try trimmedAsset.export(to: destinationURL)
    }
} catch let error {
    print(" \(error)")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add kUTTypeMovie in the setMediaTypes array and it will work.