# iOS trim video to fixed length

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to be able to select a video from the photo library and pick out 15 seconds of video from an existing clip. Is there a way to force the trim to be a fixed length?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439707/how-to-trim-the-video-using-avfoundation

This Question has a similar kind of answer. Check it

Comment: @swapnil Is there a way to display the length of the video when trimming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) property, [`videoMaximumDuration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/videoMaximumDuration) to the fixed length you want. From the documentation:

> The maximum duration, in seconds, for a video recording.

`@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval videoMaximumDuration
Discussion`

> The default value for this property is 10 minutes (600 seconds). When a user taps the Share button to send a movie to MMS, MobileMe, YouTube, or another destination, an appropriate duration limit and an appropriate video quality are enforced.
>
> This property is available only if the mediaTypes property’s value array includes the kUTTypeMovie media type.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please see the following code. I hope it will be helpful to you

```
-(void)recordVideo{
   imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
   imagePicker.delegate = self;
   imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
   imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *) kUTTypeMPEG4, nil];
   imagePicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720;
   [imagePicker setVideoMaximumDuration:15.0f];
  sourceType = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];
  if (![sourceType containsObject:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie]) {
    NSLog(@"Can not Save Video");
 }
 [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

Make sure that, you have to set **allowsEditing** to **YES** before presenting the controller.