# How to customize the record video and choose the start and end frame in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I'm working on the simple iPhone application to record the video and then choose the start and end frames of the videos to trim the selected duration of it.

I'm using UIImagepickercontroller to record the video and use it for choose the start and end frames to achieve this.

But i couldn't control the UI like changing the play/rewind icon position , adding the custom icons and choosing the frame selection.

Choosing the start and end frames is difficult to choose the frames.

Is it possible to achieve this by AVPlayer or any other framework ?

Is any other third party library to achieve to this ?

I would like to achieve the ui as below image :

[image]

Comment: Refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439707/how-to-trim-the-video-using-avfoundation

Comment: Erik, Thank you.. But its not working only if i choose a video from the album.. I get start/end time if i record a video and choose the frames.