# How to get video from UIImagePickerController with maximum duration

Tags: ios, objective-c, editor, picker

I have implemented a UIImagePickerController in my application with a videoMaximumDuration of 10 seconds.

However in the callback from the delegate imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: in the NSDictionary i can only retrieve the original video (and not the trimmed video) from the PHAsset.

NSLog from the dictionary when i choose a video.

```
info: {
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie";
    UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset = "<PHAsset: 0x1149af010> E2FA31C6-0232-4A89-8DE5-A4C8CBC98D97/L0/001 mediaType=2/0, sourceType=1, (540x960), creationDate=2019-06-05 14:01:07 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0 ";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=E2FA31C6-0232-4A89-8DE5-A4C8CBC98D97&ext=mov";
}
```

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.videoMaximumDuration = 10.0f;
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        picker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeAVIMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeVideo, (NSString*)kUTTypeMPEG4, (NSString*)kUTTypeImage];
        picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

        [self._viewCtrl presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

How can i access the trimmed video ?
Thank

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141620/8893230) it might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but changing `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` by `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` fixed it (now show `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` in the NSSDictionary)